# How to filter data basis on Date using Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-workspace

I am trying to automate user suspension basis on their last working day. So basically HR puts information on Google Sheet, Column "A" = Last Working Day (dd/mm/yyyy) "B" = User Email Id (adbc@abc.com) "C" = Need to be deactivated or not ?

[image: 1]

Now I want to automate this thing that at every day 7:30 PM IST Script will automatically get triggered and it will suspend those users who have last working day as today and Column "C" = Yes. There will be future as well as past data. It should only affect the data which have LWD = today & Column "C" === Yes.

I tried creating a filter using App Script, but somehow it's not working. The script is below:

```
function Test() {
  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(""); // Spreadsheet ID
  var Sheet = SS.getSheetByName(""); // Sheet Name
  var data = Sheet.getRange(2, 1, 5, 4).getValues();
  var date = new Date();
  var finalData = data.filter(function(item) {
    return item[0] === date &&
      item[3] === "Yes"
  });
  Logger.log(finalData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `return item[0] === date &&item[3] === "Yes"`

with this `return item[0] = date && item[2] === "Yes"` also for triggers, in google script editor only you have it in menu try that

[Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually)

Comment: Hi Shiva, That will give me data which have date in column "A"and "Yes" in Column "C". I want to filter only that data which have Column A = Today's Date and Column C ="Yes".